# how to manipulate string.format with if else in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, string.format

i have a string in which i am using String.format in this i want to remove the 2nd parameter if  string iteration will come as ="" or NULL and also want to remove the 
. `AND [Source].[System.IterationPath] IN ('{1}')` from the String that will be formed.

```
    public void GetProjectInfo(string projectname,string Iteration)
            {
    string querystring = string.Format("select [System.Id], [System.Title],[Story.Author],[Story.Owner],[System.AssignedTo]," +
" [System.WorkItemType],[Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints],[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority]," +
"[Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort], [Actual.Effort.Completed]" +
",[System.State]," +
 "[System.IterationPath]" +
 " FROM WorkItemLinks" +
 " WHERE" +
" ([Source].[System.TeamProject]='{0}'" +
 " and [Source].[System.WorkitemType] IN ('Feature', 'Bug', 'Product Backlog Item', 'Task')" +
    " AND [Source].[System.IterationPath] IN ('{1}'))"//this line of code will be removed along with iteration parameter 
    +
    " and ([System.Links.LinkType]='System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward')" +
    " ORDER BY [System.Id] " +
    " mode (Recursive)", projectname, Iteration);

    }
```

Comment: What you mean by *string iteration will come ..* ?

Comment: means if iteration parameter value ="" or NULL

Comment: Do you know that you could remove all that messy + and "" just prepending the @ character in front to the opening quote of the string?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public void GetProjectInfo(string projectname, string Iteration)
{
    var query =
            $@"SELECT 
                 [System.Id], [System.Title],[Story.Author],[Story.Owner],[System.AssignedTo],
                 [System.WorkItemType],[Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints],[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority],
                 [Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort], [Actual.Effort.Completed], [System.State], [System.IterationPath] 
             FROM WorkItemLinks 
             WHERE ([Source].[System.TeamProject]='{projectname}' 
                   AND [Source].[System.WorkitemType] IN ('Feature', 'Bug', 'Product Backlog Item', 'Task') 
                   ${(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Iteration) ? "" : $"AND [Source].[System.IterationPath] IN ('{Iteration}'))") }
                   AND ([System.Links.LinkType]='System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward')
            ORDER BY [System.Id] mode (Recursive)";
}
```

*Note*

string concatenation is a **bad practice** for building a SQL Query, there is a thread of [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)